# How to pass @Input() params to an angular 2 component created with DynamicComponentLoader

Tags: angular

The DynamicContentLoader docs don't explain how I can properly load a child component's inputs. Let's say I have a child like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: '<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="thing.Name" />'
})
class ChildComponent {
  @Input() thing : any;
}
```

and a parent like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: 'Parent (<div #child></div>)'
})
class MyApp {
  thing : any;
  constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, elementRef: ElementRef) {
    dcl.loadIntoLocation(ChildComponent, elementRef, 'child');
  }
}
```

How should I go about passing `thing` into the child component such that the two components can be data bound against the same thing.

I tried to do this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: 'Parent (<div #child></div>)'
})
class MyApp {
  thing : any;
  constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, elementRef: ElementRef) {
    dcl.loadIntoLocation(ChildComponent, elementRef, 'child').then(ref => {
        ref.instance.thing = this.thing;
    });
  }
}
```

It sort of works, but they are not synchronised as you would expect.

Basically I am trying to achieve the same thing that would have been achieved by using ng-include in angular 1 where the child is a dynamically determined component and shares the model with its parent.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: You can use EventEmitter for this case, check this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SHc0yeUOSqn0pITXztHa?p=preview)

Comment: That's an interesting idea and makes me think. I'm not sure it is entirely suitable for my scenario. What I'm really trying to do is have two components which both represent two halves of a form which is editing a single model. Thanks though, I think it will still come in useful.

Answer (score 5):

I made some tests for your problem and I can't reproduce it.

Here is the content of my child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
    <div>
      Child component - <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="thing.name" />
    </div>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() thing : any;

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Here is the content of the parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-dyn-parent',
  template: `
    <div>
      Parent component - <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="thing.name" /> (<br/>
        <div #child></div>
      <br/>)
    </div>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  thing : any;
  constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.thing = { name: 'test name' };
    dcl.loadIntoLocation(ChildComponent, elementRef, 'child')
                     .then((compRef:ComponentRef) => {
      compRef.instance.thing = this.thing;
    });
  }
}
```

So I have two inputs bound on the same element: one within the parent component and one in the child one. When I update the value in one input, the other value is updated in the other input.

So both components share the same instance and can update it. Perhaps I missed something in your use case, so feel free to tell me!

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: This solution works well if `thing` is an object or an array, because the parent and child both get a reference to the same object.  However, if `thing` is a primitive type (String, number, boolean), it doesn't work -- parent and child each get their own primitive. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MuvEyCLOzNX3J28ZI3UY?p=preview). Eric's solution with the EventEmitter seems to be a more universal solution (it works with reference types and primitive types).

Comment: Interesting that it works for you. That's encouraging I guess. Perhaps there is something I am missing. My parent component is part of a nested route. Also I have nested forms involved in the parent and child components. Perhaps that is interfering with things. I must say that the ng2 forms stuff is quite confusing so possibly I have something wrong. I will try stripping it down a bit and see if I can get the same results as you.

Comment: Yes, you're right, Mark! Sorry I missed your comment... If you want to support primitive types as well, we should leverage EventEmitter like Eric did. Thanks for pointing this out!